# Unable to change image size

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am using an image inside a BoxLayout of which `size_hint_y` is set to None
And the images seems to have no response to any attempt to change the size,
And i suspect that the issue arises only on using `size_hint_y:None`

It works fine if i remove the size_hint_y parameter, but doing so will affect the other widgets positioning , so how can i do this without avoiding the  `size_hint_y:None` Parameter

Code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

Kv=("""

BoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'
    size_hint_y:None
    height:self.minimum_height 
    spacing:5
    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical' 
        size_hint_y:None
        height:self.minimum_height     
        spacing:20            
        
        Image:
                 
            size_hint:None,None
            source:"/storage/3666-3432/Download/Lion.jpg"                       

      

""")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(Kv)
        
MyApp().run()
```

Edit

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

Kv=("""


ScrollView:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        size_hint_y:None
        height:self.minimum_height 
        spacing:5
    
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'vertical' 
            size_hint_y:None
            height:self.minimum_height     
            spacing:20            
        
            Image:
                height:2000
                size_hint:None,None
                source:"/storage/3666-3432/Download/Lion.jpg"                       

      

""")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(Kv)
        
MyApp().run()
```

In the above code you can see that when the height parameter is used, the image size dosen't change and rather a huge space is being created at the either sides of the image[image]

Comment: In the `BoxLayout`, the `size_hint_y: None` is required for the `height:self.minimum_height` to function correctly. However, another requirement for `height:self.minimum_height` to function correctly is that the children of the `BoxLayout` must have well defined `heights`. Your `Image` widget does not have a well defined height. A well defined `height` cannot be provided by a `size_hint`, so I suggest adding at least a `height` attribute to your `Image`. Actually, the `Image` gets the default size of `(100,100)`.

Comment: @John Anderson it's been while since I've seen your answers , you are back.! , talking about the height, i tried adjusting the height before and i did it on ScrollView ,the image size didn't changed much rather the space between the image and the other widgets got really big

Comment: @John Anderson any idea ?? Or any other alternative solution

Comment: Can't really get any more specific without a [mcve].

Comment: @John Anderson I've added another code which uses ScrollView and height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `Image` `height` to 2000, and so the `Image` widget will have a `height` of 2000. The `width` of the `Image` will be the default value of 100 because you are not setting that value and `size_hint_x` is `None` for the `Image`. However, by default, the `Image` widget has `allow_stretch` of `False` and `keep_ratio` of `True`, so the texture will be 100 wide and an appropriately ratioed height (not 2000).

I'm not entirely sure what you are attempting to accomplish, but if you want the `Image` to stretch, you should add `allow_stretch: True` to the `Image` and either add a `width` for the `Image`, or change `size_hint:None,None` to `size_hint:1,None`.

Comment: It works fine right now and the lion can freely stretch now... , i had no idea about what was going wrong, i tried out every possible Parameters to change image size including the  allow_stretch function and none of them worked, until i set ```size_hint:1,None ```, with ```allow_stretch:True``` and a ```height```